# Get VS Code to auto generate function outlines

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In other IDE's with other languages, I'm used to writing calls to functions that don't exist, passing parameters to them. I then get an auto suggestion that the function doesn't exist, and the IDE will create it (in the right place) for me. I can then go and populate it.

I don't seem to find any information on how to achieve this with VSCode and python.

I have the following extensions installed:
python
pylance
pylint

My project root directory is explicitly named in .vscode/settings.json with:

```
{
  "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["my-root-project-folder-name"]
}
```

What further is required, including any custom extension that might achieve this?